# Can anyone simplify my vb.net code

Tags: vb.net

can anyone help me simplify this code, because I need to extend the same way in much more line, this make my code look bulky

```
    Private Sub tb11_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles tb11.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar >= ("1") And e.KeyChar <= ("9") Then
        tb11.Text = e.KeyChar
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub tb12_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles tb12.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar >= ("1") And e.KeyChar <= ("9") Then
        tb12.Text = e.KeyChar
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub tb13_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles tb13.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar >= ("1") And e.KeyChar <= ("9") Then
        tb13.Text = e.KeyChar
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub tb14_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles tb14.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar >= ("1") And e.KeyChar <= ("9") Then
        tb14.Text = e.KeyChar
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @BlakesSeven please see [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5778/23788) - use existing, valid close reasons ("too broad" or "opinion-based", as applicable); being on-topic on CR isn't a valid close reason on SO. Cheers!

Comment: That said, this question would need a better title and a description of what's being achieved here (i.e. more context), to be well-received on Code Review.

Comment: @Mat'sMug That said, there **is** a clear desscription here which is *"can anyone simplify my code"*. While there "may" be a problem to solve here, that is not what is being asked. So a learning experience here is to *"Ask a clear and correct question for your problem"*. Hence my opinion to close. The quality of provided answers tends to agree with me here.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I'm only saying that the consensus between moderators on both sites is that "because it belongs on CR" isn't a valid close reason to use on SO. I'm also saying that "can anyone simplify my code" would get downvoted on CR, because *every single question on that site* is essentially asking that or a variant of it, and that this question would make a poor migration candidate because there is no description *of what the code is doing and why* ("context") and a good review would require more than just this boiled-down snippet which, in my own opinion, is perfectly suitable for SO.

Comment: @BlakesSeven: then vote to close as "unclear" and *optionally* use a flag to request migration.

Comment: @MartijnPieters To be clear about this. This question was in the low quality queue. Close votes for any reason should work to suspend activity ( once held ) so should that not help the OP with time to clarify anyway? The question looks like being closed and there is an "answer" for better or worse, so I would have thought the horse has bolted. But if you really believe I have done something "wrong" here then please open a chat where I'm willing to listen. But I would have said this was already done.

Comment: @BlakesSeven see the link Matt has given; I understand what you are trying to do but the first rule of migration is that we only migrate stuff that is actually off topic here so we should use the existing off-topic options where possible. You are welcome me to add an additional comment to point to CR after voting to close.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Above all the event listeners functions you are checking the same condition
you can move that condition to a other method and pass your object to it

Answer (score 5):

Make a single event handler that runs the check then changes the sender text. Remember to cast the sender to a `TextBox` first though.

```
Private Sub TextBox_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) 
Handles tb11.KeyPress, tb12.KeyPress, tb13.KeyPress, tb14.KeyPress

    If e.KeyChar >= ("1") And e.KeyChar <= ("9") Then
        DirectCast(sender, TextBox).Text = e.KeyChar
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have a **lot** of these, you can also leave off the `Handles` section of the function declaration and use the `AddHandler` keyword to assign them at run-time.

Comment: thanks a lot, i just now try google to find out, but still cannot, because i didn't know about the directcast